# C# visual studio: Remove entire row or column from Array, and how to show two dimensional array in the output?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

i have 8x6 array and I need to delete first two rows and the last two columns and change it to 6x4

```
45   778 0   0   0    0 
1531 87  0   0   0    0 
1391 619 115 115 1446 674 
1278 330 150 150 1351 403 
1037 460 178 178 1124 547 
695  454 202 202 794  553 
911  119 197 197 1007 215 
534  91  195 195 629  186
```

i need to change the above matrix to :

```
1391 619 115 115 
1278 330 150 150  
1037 460 178 178  
695  454 202 202  
911  119 197 197  
534  91  195 195
```

also how can I display this matrix in the output ?? I tried 
`Console.WriteLine( myArray.GetUpperBound(0));` but didn't work!!

Comment: Have you tried anything else? GetUpperBound does "The index of the last element of the specified dimension in the array, or -1 if the specified dimension is empty."

Comment: You can't resize a 2-D matrix - all you can do is create a new 2-D matrix and copy the desired values into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only thing I can think of is create a new array and then using a double for loop read out of the one and into the other?

Will be interesting to see if anyone knows a better way to do this

The exact function to do this would be

```
private static int[,] CopyArray(int[,] array, int fromX, int fromY, int lengthX, int lengthY)
{
    int[,] result = new int[lengthX, lengthY];
    for (int x = 0; x < result.GetLength(0); x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < result.GetLength(1); y++)
        {
            result[x, y] = array[x + fromX, y + fromY];
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

A full example of this is posted to my GitHub account (http://go.beeming.net/2dyzJY6).

Comment: Please provide some example for your suggestion. Otherwise this best fits as a comment..

Comment: Added the function and also with a link to the program.cs in GitHub with full example =)

Comment: thanks man this did what I need